# Killing Subprocess in Ubuntu NOT the Parent?

Tags: java, tomcat, kill, jboss

I want to kill a process in Ubuntu.

I have Java installed and Running JBOSS & Tomcat at background. I need to kill Tomcat after deployment but when I kill it JBOSS is going too.

I had to use

```
kill -9 pidofjava
killall tomcat
```

But status is still same.

What I need to do to kill a process attribute? I mean subprocess?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop  through the process list, identifying children
with the same parent and kill them one by one.

Attribution: http://www.unix.com/17901-post4.html

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
  echo "Enter parent process id  [type quit for exit]"
  read ppid

  if [ $ppid -eq "quit" -o $ppid -eq "QUIT" ];then
     exit 0
  fi

  for i in `ps -ef| awk '$3 == '$ppid' { print $2 }'`
  do
      echo killing $i
      kill $i
  done
done
```

You can also kill by session id but that get's the parent *and* the
children.

https://serverfault.com/questions/40303/how-do-you-kill-a-process-tree-in-linux

`ps -eo pid,ppid,sess,cmd -u ppetraki  | grep whoami`

`pkill -9 -s SESS_ID`

Using the information from the later, you could build a simpler
tool that targeted only children.

Answer (score 1):

Usually processes check whether their subprocesses are still alive and might shut down themselves if one of the subprocesses is aborted.